# How to build Bootstrap 4 with jQuery slim and new @popperjs with Laravel-mix?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-6, laravel-mix

The content of `webpack.mix.js`:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/vendor.js', 'public/js');
```

The content of `vendor.js`:

```
window.Popper = require('@popperjs/core').default;

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

After the build, in the `public/js/vendor.js` file I can clearly see that `@popperjs` and `jquery.slim.js` gets included on top of `jquery` and old `popperjs` (they get duplicated).

I know that this happens because `node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js` has `require('jquery'), require('popper.js')` as dependencies.

**How can I build the assets with new `@popperjs` and `jquery.slim.js` without the old `popperjs` and full `jquery` version?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could help you out: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/#importing-javascript

So you can import plugins individually and use a newer popperjs version. But count on, it might be instable for bootstrap 4 to use a newer popperjs version.

Btw: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/29842 chance in bootstrap 5.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 is not compatible with Popper 2 (`npm@popperjs/core`), you need to use Popper 1 (`npm@popper.js`)

Answer (score 1):

Ref:

> I know that this happens because `node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js` has `require('jquery')`, `require('popper.js')` as dependencies.

Incorrect.
Bootstrap does not load either jQuery or popper for you. You have to load them yourself, regardless of what package manager you use.

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/#package-managers

> `require('bootstrap')` will load all of Bootstrap’s jQuery plugins onto the jQuery object.

All you get is a warning in console when installing the `npm` Bootstrap package if it doesn't find a suitable `jquery` package version in your dependencies.

This is also quite easy to test: simply don't include jQuery before requiring Bootstrap, open the console, get a bag of popcorn, hit refresh button and enjoy the show.

---

To tell webpack `jquery` is to be found at `window.jQuery` (whenever it might be required or imported in your app), you should specify it in webpack config's `externals`:

```
externals: {
  jquery: 'window.jQuery'
}
```

With this, anywhere in your app where you use `import * as $ from 'jquery'` it will actually use whatever `window.jQuery` is at the time the require/import is done.

---

As far as reputable sources go for answering *"Which are Bootstrap's dependencies?"* question, the only source is [Getting Started](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start).

And here's where they specify in clear jQuery is not included: [#js-files](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/contents/#js-files)